# How to use datetime to calculate duration and stop time?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I'm using Python 2.7 and want to use the datetime functions to calculate a user defined time to run a small pump. I know I'm missing something obvious  but I've searched until I can't see straight. I have a textCtrl that the user will enter the minutes he wants the pump to run. Then a button click will start the scheduler and check to see if it's time to turn off the pump:

```
def timedPump(val):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    timeOff = now + datetime.timedelta(minutes=int(val))
    if timeOff > now:
        print 'pumpOn'
    else:
        print 'pumpOff'
    return True
```

The problem is that `datetime.datetime.now()` updates everytime. How do I make it so that `now` = the time that the button was clicked?

Comment: You need to put your first two lines of code in another function (e.g. "startTimer") that then returns `timeOff`, and invoke that function with your textCtrl. You can then use timedPump to check whether `timeOff > datetime.datetime.now()`.

Comment: Pass the `now` value you want used to the function when you call it: i.e. `timedPump(datetime.datetime.now(), val)`. (You'll need to change the function definition according, of course.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some information missing as to how timedPump is evaluated. I guess it's a simple loop.

What needs to happen is there have to be two functions, one that sets a turnOff-time and one that evaluates weather to turn on / off the pump.
This can be implemented as two methods of a class:

```
class PumpControl(object):
    def setTime(self, val):
        now = datetime.now()
        self.timeOff=now + timedelta(minutes=int(val))
        print 'pumpOn'

    def checkTime(self):
        if self.timeOff < datetime.now():
            print 'pumpOff'
```

This way you would create a PumpControl object and then repeat checkTime:

```
controller = PumpControl()
#inside your loop
controller.checkTime()
#when you want to set the time
controller.setTime(val)
```

This should work across threads as well, so you can have one thread repeating and another asking for the time.

Comment: I am just starting to use threads. I would like to add additional tasks. Should I make each task a seperate class and then run seperate loops for each class in the main frame?

Comment: @Cathy_Hanna I have to admit that I don't use threads that much myself. However, If you create a controller-object in each thread (that is, call PumpControl() within the thread, not outside), I don't see how they would interfere.

Answer (score 1):

This would be my solution to the problem:

```
from time import sleep

def pumpcheck(timer_in_minutes):
    time_clicked = datetime.datetime.now()
    now = time_clicked
    timeDiff = datetime.timedelta(minutes=int(timer_in_minutes))
    while (time_clicked + timeDiff > now):
        print 'pumpOn'
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        sleep(2)
    print 'pumpOff'
```

It saves the time when the button was pushed and then checks in a loop, if the time is rfeached, if not, it update the current time, says pump is still on and sleep for a little while to not bloack cpu recources. When the time is reached, it says pumpoff

Comment: Although this worked perfectly, I am afraid that when I start adding more tasks to the overall project, the sleep function will start to interfer(?).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something outside the scope of a single function. Either split the logic into two functions, or use a class to preserve `start_time`